# error LNK2005 in VS 2010

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting below error. I can not understnad where does it happening? Whre it is going wrong.
I am developing some code as,

`abc.h`

```
#include<vector>
vector<string> vect;
vector<string>::iterator ab;
```

`def.c`

```
#include "abc.h"

    vect.push_back("a");
    vect.push_back("b");
    for(ab = vect.begin(); ab != vect.end(); ab++)
    {
    if(*ab == "b")
    {
    FIle *file->fun();
    }
```

`abc.c`

```
#include "abc.h"

    File::file()
    {
    vect.insert(1, "Something");
    }
```

I am getting an error as

```
"class std::_Vector_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > testCase" (?testCase@@3V?$_Vector_iterator@V?$_Vector_val@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@@std@@A) already defined in abc.obj
1>GTestThread.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > vect" (?vect@@3V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in abc.obj
1>D:/ fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
vector<string> vect;
vector<string>::iterator ab;
```

is a definition in a header, meaning the you'll break the one definition rule when you include the header in multiple translation units. Change it to:

```
//abc.h
extern vector<string> vect;
extern vector<string>::iterator ab;
```

to make it a declaration and move the definition in a single implementation file:

```
//abc.c
#include "abc.h"
vector<string> vect;
vector<string>::iterator ab;
```

I'm still wondering how your `def.c` compiles, you can't just paste statements in an implementation file outside a context.

Also, C++ has extensions `.cc` or `.cpp` (others too I think), not `.c`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie true, didn't see the extension.

Comment: I have also tried with extern but the problem still lies

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak you haven't done everything I said you should in the answer. If you had, and still get the error, your compiler is broken.

Comment: Thanks Man. Instead of making the chages in `abc.c`, I was doing it in `def.c`. But good troubleshoot man.Thanks

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak the initial change (with extern) should be made in the header.

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't *define* things like `vect` in header files since every C++ file that includes it will get its own copy, hence the duplicate symbol warning.

*Declare* it in the header with:

```
extern vector <string> vect;
```

and then define it in *one* of the C++ files.